# How to convert a string of HashSet to a 2D vector in c++ ? This is a 3-sum problem in leetcode

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, data-structures, c++17

```
// nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]
// result should be = {{-1,-1,2},{-1,0,1}}

vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        unordered_set<string> s;
        for(int start1=0; start1<nums.size(); start1++){
            for(int start2=start1+1; start2<nums.size(); start2++){
                for(int start3=start2+1; start3<nums.size(); start3++){
                    string str = "";
                    if(nums[start1]+nums[start2]+nums[start3] == 0){
                        str +=  to_string(nums[start1])+
                                to_string(nums[start2])+
                                to_string(nums[start3]);
                    }
                    s.insert(str); //s{"-1-12","-101"}
                }
         }
 }
```

**After inserting values to set s, s look as follows**
`s{"-1-12","-101"}`
The problem is how I can convert that set to a 2d vector in c++.
*I wanted to return a 2D vector of integers.*

Comment: If you want integers (actually vectors of integers), why are you creating strings?

Comment: What did you try? What specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: The algorithm is working, but you just concatenate all strings together into a single string. The numbers `-1`, `-1` and `2` becomes the string `"-1-12"`. You should probably have a vector of integers, instead of a string, then append to the vector, and lastly add the vector to the set.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to return a 2D vector of integers and declare the function to return `vector<vector<int>>`, which is fine - but you never return anything from the function.
- Instead of populating a `vector<int>` in your inner loop, you've chosen to populate a `string`. That must be changed.
- Using an `unordered_set<vector<int>>` will however not work "out of the box" because there is no standard hashing function for `vector<int>`. I suggest using a `set` instead which only requires `operator<` to be defined, which it is for `vector<int>`.
- *"`result should be = {{-1,-1,2},{-1,0,1}}`"* - but that's not what your algorithm produces. It produces `{{},{-1,-1,2},{-1,0,1}}` since it'll insert elements even when `nums[start1]+nums[start2]+nums[start3] != 0`.

Example with suggested fixes:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> threeSum(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    std::set<std::vector<int>> s;          // using a set<vector<int>> instead
    for (size_t start1 = 0; start1 < nums.size(); start1++) {
        for (size_t start2 = start1 + 1; start2 < nums.size(); start2++) {
            for (size_t start3 = start2 + 1; start3 < nums.size(); start3++) {
                if (nums[start1] + nums[start2] + nums[start3] == 0) {
                    // only insert when a match is found to produce the
                    // expected result
                    s.insert({nums[start1], nums[start2], nums[start3]});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // populate the std::vector<std::vector<int>> by using the begin() and
    // end() iterators of `s`:
    return {s.begin(), s.end()};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6M3McaWj1)

---

Since copying the inner `vector<int>`s may be an expensive operation, you can, since C++17, also *move* them from the `set<vector<int>>` into the `vector<vector<int>>`.

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> threeSum(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    std::set<std::vector<int>> s;

    for (size_t start1 = 0; start1 < nums.size(); start1++) {
        for (size_t start2 = start1 + 1; start2 < nums.size(); start2++) {
            for (size_t start3 = start2 + 1; start3 < nums.size(); start3++) {
                if (nums[start1] + nums[start2] + nums[start3] == 0) {
                    s.insert({nums[start1], nums[start2], nums[start3]});
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> rv;

    for(std::set<std::vector<int>>::iterator it = s.begin(), next;
        it != s.end(); it = next) 
    {
        next = std::next(it);
        // extract and move:
        rv.push_back(std::move(s.extract(it).value()));
    }
    return rv;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3xEvhsf6a)